# jQuery autocomplete select event to auto submit form not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have the following code, autocomplete is working perfectly, but it is not submitting the form when a value is chosen whether by Enter or click:
js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete(
                {
         source:'autocomplete.php',
                 minLength:1,
                 autoFocus: true,
                 delay: 100,
                 select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#searchForm").submit();
                 }
    });
});
```

my php file contains this form:

```
<form action="search_results.php" method="GET" id="searchForm" name="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" >
    <input type="submit" value="GO!" id="submit">
</form>
```

I do not know why auto submit is not working! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have some sort of form validation that may block the normal submit?

Comment: Nothing, The only other javascript on the page is facebook login SDK, but it is not doing any form validation.

Comment: And the `#search` input is correctly updated `$("#search").val(ui.item.label);`?

Comment: yes, when I add alert(ui.item.label); to the select function, the alert contains the correct selected value

Comment: That's not my question exactly: is the field itself being updated?

Comment: Yes, whenever I scroll through autocomplete list, the value displayed in the search field is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your submit `input` has an ID of `submit`. This is apparently the same problem as when the `name` attribute is "submit", jQuery doesn't like it.

Just change the ID of the submit `input` like:

```
<input type="submit" value="GO!" id="submitForm">
```

Comment: I'm glad, because I've been scratching my head... until I remembered I had a similar problem once :)

Comment: Never imagined this could the cause. Great job :)